# No Home Page Question

Tags: workspace

The version of SharePoint on my company issued laptop is "SharePoint Workspace".  Under File/New it does not give me the option to create a home page/site; only "SharePoint Workspace", "Groove Workspace", "Shared Folder", "Workspace from Template" and "Workspace from Archive".

Is there a way to create a home page using this version of SharePoint or can this only be done using the version called "SharePoint Control Administration"? Thank you.

Shawn

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Workspace allows you to connect to an existing SharePoint site to view and collaborate on documents (it does quite a bit more, but that's the main gist of it).

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-workspace/

To get your own site, you need to speak to your SharePoint administrator or IT administrator. Then you should be able to connect your SharePoint Workspace to your personal site.

Comment: I spoke to them and they granted me access to the home site.  Thank you!